# Drawing arrow heads without the tails in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows

I have an ellipse in a TikZ diagram and I would like to indicate a direction using an arrow head, but do not wish to draw the path leading up to the arrow head.

I currently have

```
\draw[->] (0,2) arc (90:45:1 and 2);
\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and 2);
```

but I'd like the arc leading up to the arrow to be invisible (so it is not redrawing over the ellipse), so that it's just the head showing.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use path decorations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{<}}}
]
  \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) ellipse (1 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

(Tested with TikZ 3.0.1a)

You can use the `tips` key to configure drawing of arrow tips. The initial value of the `tips` key is `on draw`, so initially, arrow tips are only drawn when the path itself is drawn, too. But you can set the `tips` key to `true` to draw arrow tips even for undrawn paths.

```
\path[tips, ->] (0,2) arc (90:45:1 and 2);
\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and 2);
```

See Chapter 16.2 (Where and When Arrow Tips Are Placed) of the [TikZ and PGF Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: This is perfect.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 9):

Tested with TikZ 3.0:

- load the `arrows.meta` library instead of `arrows`
- add `draw opacity=0` as option to `\draw`, but not to the arrow, such as `>={LaTeX[]}`

The tail will be completely opaque, i.e. will not be shown, only the head will be visible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->,>={LaTeX[]},draw opacity=0] (0,2) arc (90:45:1 and 2);
  %\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and 2);% commented out to see only the tip
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arrow tip without tail]

Comment: Shows only a blank page. Texlive 2019.

Comment: @vonbrand Just re-tested: it shows an arrow on an otherwise blank page, as expexted. Did you zoom in and look? It's very small. I checked with an older TeX Live though, on my business laptop where I didn't install TL 2019 yet.

Comment: It does not work, it seems to work only with filled arrows but it draws only the filler, not the border. With other kind of arrows it doesn't draw anything.

Answer (score 6):

Any easy to type but slightly hackish solution is to use a very small path for the arrow:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and 2);
    \draw[->] (0,0) ++ (45:1 and 2) arc (45:44.9:1 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To get a flexible "clean" solution one can use markings:

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and 2);
    \draw[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{>}}},decorate]
        (0,2) arc (90:45:1 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The marking can also be directly applied to the ellipse (which is drawn counterclockwise from 0 degrees):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [decoration={markings,mark=at position 1/8 with {\arrowreversed{>}}},postaction={decorate}] 
        (0,0) ellipse (1 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

See Section 27.6 of the TikZ manual for the general syntax of the `mark` option.

Comment: Yes, that should work, but it doesn't seem like a clean solution (not that I currently have one). Another non-clean solution is to just remove the ellipse command and get tikz to draw an arc the entire perimeter of the ellipse, but I'd like to know a general solution to my problem of drawing arrow heads.

Comment: I added a second solution that is more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very simply in plain [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it).  The `arrowhead` macro takes an arbitrary path as an argument, and returns the path of an arrowhead at the end of the given path.

Using appropriate `subpath` commands you can position an arrowhead anywhere you like along a path.  The standard `arrowhead` produces a rather solid looking arrow, so you might prefer the open or curly versions included below.

[image: An ellipse with arrowheads]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

vardef open_arrowhead expr p =
  save q,e; path q; pair e;
  e = point length p of p;
  q = gobble(p shifted -e cutafter makepath(pencircle scaled 2ahlength))
    cuttings;
  (q rotated .5ahangle & reverse q rotated -.5ahangle)  shifted e
enddef;

vardef curly_arrowhead expr p =
  save q,e; path q, q'; pair e;
  e = point length p of p;
  q = gobble(p shifted -e cutafter makepath(pencircle scaled 2ahlength))
    cuttings;
  q' = q rotatedabout(point 1/2 of q,90);
  (point 0 of q' { direction 0 of q' } 
  .. 
  { direction infinity of q  } point infinity of q { - direction infinity of q } 
  .. 
  { direction infinity of q' } point infinity of q'
  ) shifted e
enddef;

beginfig(1);
path ellipse; 
ellipse = fullcircle xscaled 2cm yscaled 4cm;
draw ellipse withcolor .63 red;
ahlength := 3;
filldraw arrowhead subpath (2,3) of ellipse;
draw open_arrowhead subpath (2,1) of ellipse;
draw curly_arrowhead subpath (1,2) of ellipse;
endfig;
end.
```

Notice that you need to `draw` my open-ended arrowheads, whereas the standard one needs `filldraw`.  Note also how you can get reverse paths neatly with `subpath`.