# How to draw a not fully-connected elliptic arrow using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, arrows

I want to draw an arrow like this:

[image]

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7458/how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line-of-a-circle-and-how-to-position-t) question which is kind of similar, but it relies on that the circle is fully drawn. What I want to do is to draw an ellipsis which has a small gap in it and an arrow on one of the edges.

It would also be cool if the gap was created by actually not drawing the line - not by drawing some white on top of the ellipsis.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an `arc` path with `start angle` and `end angle` not adding up to 360.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-latex, thick, rotate=-30] (0,0) arc [start angle=-190, end angle=160, x radius=1cm, y radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's awesome! And so _simple_!