# Elliptic arrow line in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

How can I draw an elliptic line with arrow around a line in PSTricks?

Example is visible in this picture around the 'Geographic North Pole':
[image]

The question is quite similar to [How to draw a not fully-connected elliptic arrow using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50192/how-to-draw-a-not-fully-connected-elliptic-arrow-using-tikz) but I need a solution for `pstricks`.

I tried to manage it with `pscurve` but I was not able to get an symmetric result.

Is it possible to bound this elliptic line on a `psline`, which you can see in the code below?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(6,6)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0](0,0)(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psline[origin={0.05,0}](10; 65.25)
\psline[origin={0.05,0}](10;245)
\psline[origin={0.05,0},linestyle=dashed](10; 76.75)
\psline[origin={0.05,0},linestyle=dashed](10;256.75)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to reproduce as faithfully as possible the image from your post, with the help of the `pst-eucl` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdf, x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-eucl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-family, detect-weight, detect-mode}

\begin{document}

\noindent\centering\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize
\psset{unit = 6mm}
\begin{pspicture}(-13,-10)(12.5,10)
    \psframe*[linecolor=DodgerBlue4!65!Black](-13,-10)(12.5,10)
    \psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none](0.09,0.015){2.}}\rput(0,0){\psscaleboxto(4.25,4.0){\includegraphics{simpleglobe.eps}}}\endpsclip
    \psset{ linecolor=Yellow1, PointSymbol=none, PointName=none}
    \psrotate(0,0){-13.25}{\pstGeonode(2; 90){A}(2; -90){B}(0,0){O}(1,0){I}%
        \psline[ linestyle=dashed, linecolor=red](10; -90)(10; 90)
        \rput[tr]{13.25}(10; 90){\begin{tabular}{>{\color{white}}r@{\quad}}North\\Magnetic\\Pole\end{tabular}}
        \rput[bl]{13.25}(10; -90){\begin{tabular}{@{\quad}>{\color{white}}l}South\\Magnetic\\Pole\end{tabular}}
        \rput[tl]{13.25}(10;78.5){\begin{tabular}{>{\color{white}}l}Geographic\\North Pole\end{tabular}}
        \rput[br]{13.25}(10;-101.5){\begin{tabular}{>{\color{white}}l@{\,}}\color{white}Geographic\\South Pole\end{tabular}}
        \psline[linecolor=SeaGreen3](10;78.5)(-10;78.5)
        \psarc(0,0){7}{78.64}{89.86}\rput[bc]{-5.75}(7.3; 83){\color{white}\scriptsize\ang{11,5}}
        \psellipticarc[arrows=->, rot=-5.75](8.5; 78.5)(0.7,0.3){100}{50}
        \psellipticarc[arrows=->, rot=-5.75](-8.5; 78.5)(0.7,0.3){100}{50}
        \pstriangle*[linecolor=white](0,0.08)(0.5,1.6)
        \pstriangle*[linecolor=red](0,-0.08)(0.5,-1.6)
        \multido{\i =1 + 1}{6}{\psset{linewidth=1.2pt}%
            \psscalebox{1 1.10}{%
                \pstGeonode(\i; 180){O\i}\pstGeonode(\i; 0){P\i}
                \pstArcOAB{O\i}{A}{B}\pstArcOAB {P\i}{B}{A}
                \pstInterLC{I}{J}{O\i}{A}{N\i}{M\i}\pstInterLC{I}{J}{P\i}{A}{S\i}{R\i}
                \psdots[dotstyle=triangle*, dotscale=0.8 1](M\i)(R\i)
    }}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The graphics file was obtained from [this site](https://openclipart.org/search/?query=earth&page=10), where you can find a lot of globes. I used "A simple globe" on page 10.

Comment: Really nice. Maybe you should post a link to the drawing of the Earth.

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg:Done. I first tried to compile a code  from the pst-geo package, but didn't succeed… Note there is small problem for the placement of the first right hand side arrow, which I don't understand.

Comment: Will take a closer look at the code either later tonight or tomorrow. P.S. The picture on https://openclipart.org/detail/121483/a-simple-globe-by-jhnri4 doesn't look like the same as the one you've used.

Comment: It *is* the one I used, my dear Watson :o)

Comment: Okay. `:)` Regarding the wrong placement of the dot (triangle/arrowhead), you can try to contact Herbert and ask if he can shed some light on the 'mystery'.

Comment: @Bernard, do you know, why the first right triangle is not in line with the others?

Comment: Not at all. It was the object of the small discussion with @Svend Tveskæg. Normally, it *should* be in line. I'll submit the case to Herbert Voss.

Comment: @Bernard Has Herbert given an explanation and a solution?

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg: He answered at the beginning of this week. Unfortunately, he won't have time before summer. Perhaps I should write to the original author of the `pst-eucl`, Dominique Rodriguez.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\psellipticarc` to draw the elliptic arc, and e.g. `\psrotate` from `pstricks-add` to rotate the ellipse correctly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(6,6)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0](0,0)(-11,-11)(11,11)
\psline[origin={0.05,0}](10; 65.25)
\psline[origin={0.05,0}](10;245)
\psline[origin={0.05,0},linestyle=dashed](10; 76.75)
\psline[origin={0.05,0},linestyle=dashed](10;256.75)
\psrotate(8;65.25){62.25}{%
  \psellipticarc[arrows=->](8;65.25)(0.5,1){20}{340}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the two answers I constructed the globe with the magnetic field and the declination with pst-map3d.

But I have to notice that the usage of coordinates is not neat like in the proposed answer of Bernard.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdf, x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pst-map3d}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-family, detect-weight, detect-mode}
\SpecialCoor

\begin{document}
\noindent\centering\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize
\psset{unit = 6mm}
\begin{pspicture}[](-14,-11)(14,11) %(-4,-4)(6,6)
\rput[bl](-0.2,0){\psscalebox{0.695}{
    \begin{pspicture}(-0.1,0)(0,0.1)
        \WorldMapThreeD[PHI=25,THETA=0,RotX=-23,path=C:/data/pst-geo/data,]
    \end{pspicture}
}}

\psrotate(0,0){-13.25}{
    \psset{linecolor=black, PointSymbol=none, PointName=none}
    \pstGeonode(4.5; 90){A}(4.5; -90){B}(0,0){O}(1,0){I}%

    \multido{\i =1 + 1}{6}{\psset{linewidth=0.75pt}%
        \psscalebox{1 1.10}{%
            \pstGeonode(\i; 180){O\i}\pstGeonode(\i; 0){P\i}
            \pstArcOAB{O\i}{A}{B}\pstArcOAB{P\i}{B}{A}
            \pstInterLC{I}{J}{O\i}{A}{N\i}{M\i}\pstInterLC{I}{J}{P\i}{A}{S\i}{R\i}
            \psdots[dotstyle=triangle*, dotscale=1 1.3](M\i)(R\i)
        }}
}

\psline[origin={0,0}](10; 65.25)
\psline[origin={0,0}](10;245)
\psline[origin={0,0},linestyle=dashed](10; 76.75)
\psline[origin={0,0},linestyle=dashed](10;256.75)

\psrotate(8.6;71.25){62.25}{%
    \psellipticarc[arrows=->](8;65.25)(0.5,1){20}{340}}
\rput(2.3,10){North Magnetic Pole}
\rput(-2.3,-10){North Magnetic Pole}

\psrotate(0,0){62.25}{%
    \psellipticarc[arrows=->](-9;2.5)(0.5,1){20}{340}}
\rput(5,9.3){Geographic North Pole}
\rput(-5,-9.3){Geographic North Pole}

\psrotate(4,10){-20}{%
    \psellipticarc[arrows=<->](3.55,7)(0.8,0.2){0}{180}}
\rput(2.5,7){\ang{11.5}}

%compass
\psrotate(0,0){-13.25}{
    \pstriangle*[linecolor=white](0,0.2)(1,2.5)
    \pstriangle*[linecolor=red](0,-0.2)(1,-2.5)

}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The output (via LaTeX compiler and DVI->PS->PDF Chain) looks like this:
[image]