# Tikz: Arrowheads in the center

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, arrows

For arrows I have gone through options like ->, ->>, <-, <<- but havent found one for making the arrowhead appear in the center of the line of the curve (something like ->-) How do I do it in TIkz?

Comment: With the library `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}` see the pagraph  "Arrow Tip Markings" in the pgfmanual or look at some examples in several answers here.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but I asked a question a while ago about drawing an arrow head in the middle of an ellipse: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/drawing-arrow-heads-without-the-tails-in-tikz but I have found the syntax a bit unwieldy.

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Perhaps you prefer this kind of syntax :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[->-=.5] (0,0) to [bend left] (2,4);
 \draw[->-=.8] (0,0) to [bend right] (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you only want an arrow in the middle of a path, you can write

```
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
```

And the you just need to write :

```
 \draw[->-] (0,0) to [bend left] (2,4);
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, that's a neat syntax!

Comment: And if you add `->-/.default=0.5` at the first definition, it's practically perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to modify this so that      

    \draw[->-] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cylce; 

 would create a square such that there is an arrowhead on every edge? With the code at hand this unfortunately leads to a path where there is only 1 arrowhead at the middle of the total path length.

Answer (score 38):

You can define a new line style and decorate it. (as Altermundus commented and also given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38548/arrows-and-nodes-in-tikz/38556#38556))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{middlearrow/.style={
        decoration={markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{#1}} ,
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[middlearrow={<}] (0,0) -- (20:2);
\draw[middlearrow={>}] (0,0) -- (40:2);
\draw[middlearrow={|}] (0,0) -- (60:2);
\draw[middlearrow={stealth reversed}] (0,0) -- (80:2);
\draw[middlearrow={latex}] (0,0) arc (50:-40:-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]