# Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point on curve in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

We have very nice 
[Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33703/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (2,1);
\gettikzxy{(A)}{\ax}{\ay}
\fill[red] (\ax,\ay) circle (5pt);

\tikzset{-dot-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\fill circle (2pt);}},postaction={decorate}}} %%% in this line added a ;

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[-dot-=.5] (0,0) to [bend left] (2,4);
 \draw[-dot-=.8] (0,0) to [bend right] (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to extract x, y coordinate of a point located on the curve?  These points can be used for doing some other tasks.

> New Answer: Thanks to all

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [bend left=20]  coordinate[pos=0.7] (A)(2,4);
\draw (0,0) to [bend right=20]  coordinate[pos=0.2] (B)(2,4);
\draw[thick,red] (A) -- (B);
\gettikzxy{(A)}{\ax}{\ay}
\gettikzxy{(B)}{\bx}{\by}
\fill[blue] (\ax, \ay) circle (2pt);
\fill[blue] (\bx, \by) circle (2pt);
\draw[thick,green] (A) -- (\bx,\ay) -- (B);
\draw[thick,yellow] (A) -- (\ax,\by) -- (B);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Thank you Andrew Stacey...

Now I got a better MWE and using:

> ```
> \tikzset{pontoncurve/.style={decoration={
>   markings,
>   mark=at position #1 with {\coordinate (B);}},postaction={decorate}}}
> ```
>
> I get the coordinate. But I do not know to change **B** in `\coordinate (B)`. Should I use `\newcommand` like `\gettikzxy`?
>
> ```
> \newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
>   \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
>   \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
>   \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
> }
> ```

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33703/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (2,1);
\gettikzxy{(A)}{\ax}{\ay}
%\fill[red] (\ax,\ay) circle (5pt);

\tikzset{-dot-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\fill circle (2pt);}},postaction={decorate}}} %%% in this line added a ;

\tikzset{pontoncurve/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\coordinate (B);}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[pontoncurve=.5] (0,0) to [bend left] (2,4);
\gettikzxy{(B)}{\bx}{\by}
\draw[red] (\bx,\by) -- ++(5,1);

 \draw[-dot-=.8] (0,0) to [bend right] (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One way would be to create a vertical line (at the `x` coordinate of where you want to extract the point) with `draw=none` but name it, and then use the `intersections` library to find the intersection of this vertical line with the given curve.  An example is given in [Intersections in PGFplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/intersections-in-pgfplots), and [TikZ: Intersection of two lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31398/tikz-intersection-of-two-lines/)

Comment: If you want to get the coordinate of the marked point, simply add a coordinate to the `\fill` command you are using in the marking.  More generally, exactly how you extract the coordinates will depend somewhat on how you specify the point.  How do you want to do that?

Comment: Regarding your update, in the sample code you don't actually need to get the x and y coordinates of the point: by using `coordinate (name)` then you have a handle, `name`, by which you can refer to the point so you can write `\draw[red] (B) -- ++(5,1);` without needing `\gettikzxy` at all.  Do you want to do anything more complicated with the coordinates than just refer to them?  If not, you don't need anything more complicated than the above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need the library `decorations.markings` and you don't need the macro `gettikzxy` in your examples; perhaps with other examples, it's useful to work like this.

First `\pgfgetlastxy{\ax}{\ay}` is enough after

```
 \coordinate (A) at (2,1); 
  \pgfgetlastxy{\ax}{\ay}
```

Instead of

```
  \draw[-dot-=.5] (0,0) to [bend left]  (2,4);
```

you have

```
   \draw (0,0) to [bend left]  coordinate[pos=.5] (B)(2,4);
```

Now if you want to get the coordinates, you have several ways like

```
 \path (B);\pgfgetlastxy{\bx}{\by}
```

A complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (2,1);
\pgfgetlastxy{\ax}{\ay}    
\fill[red] (\ax,\ay) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) to [bend left]  coordinate[pos=.5] (B)(2,4);
 \draw (0,0) to [bend right] coordinate[pos=.8] (C)(2,4);
  \path (B);\pgfgetlastxy{\bx}{\by} 
  \path (C);\pgfgetlastxy{\cx}{\cy} 
  \draw[red,thick] (\bx,\by)--(\cx,\cy) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps you need to add another example to get a better answer.

**Remark**

You can get the coordinates like this with the curveto operation and now with the CVS version, it's possible with the arc operation.