# How to have a node's width match another's height?

Tags: tikz-pgf, width

I have the following situation:

[image: a bar whose width should match the height of another node]

Here, I would like the rotated node to **automatically match the height of the text node to its left**, automatically growing or shrinking depending on the amount of text/line count in it. Right now, the hard-coded `8em` only fits *almost* and needs constant care in case of changing text contents.

I assume that the fit library could help me here, but with my limited tikz code-foo I could only get misspelled pgf key errors and infinite compiles.

Here's the image as an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  node distance=2em,
  textbox/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, 
                  rectangle split part fill={black!90,black!5},
                  rectangle split part align=base,
                  draw=gray,align=center},
  barstyle/.style={fill=black!90,text=white,align=center,inner ysep=6pt,rotate=90}]

\node[barstyle,minimum width=8em] % THIS should match height of text node automatically
  (bar) {A Bar!};

\node[textbox,left=of bar.north] (textnode) {%
  {\color{white} Input}
  \nodepart{two}
  \begin{varwidth}{.8\columnwidth}
    Some pretty\\
    drawn-out text\\
    much too long\\
    to fit on a single\\
    line.
  \end{varwidth}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: *phew*, it was hard to decide which answer to accept with all those good options. In the end, I liked `style 2 args` solution most, although the `label=` makes it more difficult to use in case that text has multiple lines, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `fit` library to compute node's height. But with fitting nodes, it's better to add its contents with the `label` option.

Following code defines a `barstyle` style with two arguments, the first one is the original node which is used to get its height while the second is the node contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  node distance=2em,
  textbox/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, 
                  rectangle split part fill={black!90,black!5},
                  rectangle split part align=base,
                  draw=gray,align=center},
  barstyle/.style 2 args={fill=black!90,
            minimum width=3em, 
            fit={(#1.south) (#1.north)}, inner ysep=0pt, label={[rotate=90, white]center:#2}
    }]

\node[textbox] (textnode) {%
  {\color{white} Input}
  \nodepart{two}
  \begin{varwidth}{.8\columnwidth}
    Some pretty\\
    drawn-out text\\
    much too long\\
    to fit on a single\\
    line.
  \end{varwidth}};

\node[barstyle={textnode}{A Bar!}, right=of textnode] (bar) {};

\node[textbox, below= of textnode] (textnode2) {%
  {\color{white} Input}
  \nodepart{two}
  \begin{varwidth}{.8\columnwidth}
    Some pretty 
    drawn-out text\\
    much too long 
    to fit on a single\\
    line.
  \end{varwidth}};

\node[barstyle={textnode2}{A Bar!}, right=of textnode2] (bar2) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes whose heights match those of another node]

**2nd solution:**

A completely different solution could be to use `\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode` or `\tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode` macros from `skins` library in `tcolorbox` (see: 12.9 Extracting node dimensions) package:

```
\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode{\myheight}{textnode2}
```

saves height of `textnode2` node in macro `\myheight` which can be used in `minimum height|width|size` option from other nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  node distance=2em,
  textbox/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, 
                  rectangle split part fill={black!90,black!5},
                  rectangle split part align=base,
                  draw=gray,align=center},
  barstyle/.style={fill=black!90, text=white, align=center, inner ysep=6pt, rotate=90}
  ]

\node[textbox] (textnode) {%
  {\color{white} Input}
  \nodepart{two}
  \begin{varwidth}{.8\columnwidth}
    Some pretty\\
    drawn-out text\\
    much too long\\
    to fit on a single\\
    line.
  \end{varwidth}};

  \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode{\myheight}{textnode}

    \node[barstyle, minimum width=\myheight, right= of textnode, anchor=north] (bar) {A Bar!};

\node[textbox, below= of textnode] (textnode2) {%
  {\color{white} Input}
  \nodepart{two}
  \begin{varwidth}{.8\columnwidth}
    Some pretty 
    drawn-out text\\
    much too long 
    to fit on a single\\
    line.
  \end{varwidth}};

  \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode{\myheight}{textnode2}

    \node[barstyle, minimum width=\myheight, right=of textnode2, anchor=north] (bar2) {A Bar!};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

And, just for fun, a method using the `let` syntax from the `calc` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  node distance=2em,
  textbox/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, 
                  rectangle split part fill={black!90,black!5},
                  rectangle split part align=base,
                  draw=gray,align=center},
  barstyle/.style={fill=black!90,text=white,align=center,inner ysep=6pt,rotate=90}]

\node[textbox] (textnode) {%
  {\color{white} Input}
  \nodepart{two}
  \begin{varwidth}{.8\columnwidth}
    Some pretty\\
    drawn-out text\\
    much too long\\
    to fit on a single\\
    line.
  \end{varwidth}};

\path let
\p1=(textnode.south), \p2=(textnode.north)
in
node[barstyle,right=of textnode.south east,minimum width=\y2-\y1] 
  (bar) {A Bar!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

By looking at this previous question:

[Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point on curve in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56353/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-curve-in-tikz)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,calc}

\begin{document}
\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  node distance=2em,
  textbox/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, 
                  rectangle split part fill={black!90,black!5},
                  rectangle split part align=base,
                  draw=gray,align=center},
  barstyle/.style={fill=black!90,text=white,align=center,inner ysep=6pt,rotate=90}]

\node[textbox] (textnode) {%
  {\color{white} Input}
  \nodepart{two}
  \begin{varwidth}{.8\columnwidth}
    Some pretty\\
    drawn-out text\\
    much too long\\
    to fit on a single\\
    line.
  \end{varwidth}};
 \gettikzxy{(textnode.north)}{\ax}{\ay}
\gettikzxy{(textnode.south east)}{\bx}{\by}
\node[barstyle,minimum width=\ay-\by,anchor=south west] at($(\bx,\by)+(1cm,0.cm)$) % THIS should match height of text node automatically
  (bar) {A Bar!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]