# pgfplot addplot with predefined coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

I have a bunch of coordinates predefined, where I want to draw multiple lines in a plot by reusing coordinates. If I change a coordinate value, I only want to have to change it once, and not in multiple lists of coordinates. Hence I want to do something like the following

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\coordinate (p1) at (1,1);
\coordinate (p2) at (2,2);
\addplot coordinates{(p1)(p2)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To generate something that looks like this

[image]

But apparently life can't be that easy, because I get the following error

```
Runaway argument?
p1)(p2)\pgfplots@EOI \pgfplotsscanlinelengthcleanup 
\pgfplots@coord@stream@end 
\ETC.
Paragraph ended before \pgfplots@loop@next was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.15
```

I've tried defining the coordinates outside the axis environment as well, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas on how to use predefined coordinates in an \addplot coordinates list?

Comment: This is one of the so-called expansion problems, I believe. So in this way I think it is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/121799) but cannot solved with the same methods I think.

Comment: There must be a key to turn off the math parser of plot coordinates but I don't remember the actual name. I think if you turn it off it will read `p1` in proper context

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe you can store the values in an **external data file** and read them in. So you only have to store it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned, this is probably because pgfplots delays its expansions. This way it is possible to zoom automatically into the relevant region and so on. Therefore I cannot offer you a pretty solution. The best workaround I was able to produce is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56353/121799
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \global\edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \global\edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\newcommand{\gettikzcoordinates}[2]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{round(0.99626*\the\pgf@x/0.0283465)/1000}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{round(0.99626*\the\pgf@y/0.0283465)/1000}
  \global\edef#2{(\myx,\myy)}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (p1) at (1,1);
\coordinate (p2) at (2,2);
\begin{axis}
\gettikzcoordinates{(p1)}{\Pone}
\gettikzcoordinates{(p2)}{\Ptwo}
\addplot coordinates{\Pone\Ptwo};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code produces the desired plot. As you can check, if you move the `\begin{axis}` before the `\coordinate` statements, you'll get an error, essentially because the coordinates were not defined when they are needed. Very often you can get away by using `\edef\temp{<something>}\temp`, but in this situation I only got trapped in endless loops. (The `\gettikzxy` is not relevant here, I just wanted to indicate where I got the idea how to extract the coordinates from.)

Comment: What if those are 3D coordinates?

Comment: @aaragon: I see your comment now. If you still need an answer: There is no such thing as 3D coordinates in TikZ. When typing e.g `\coordinate (a) at (1,2,3);`, then the point at one times the `x` vector plus two times the `y` vector plus three times the `z` vector is calculated and stored in `(a)`.  All (`x`, `y`, `z` and now `a`) is 2D vectors/coordinates.