# How to use already defined co-ordinates inside pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots

The following is what I have currently.

```
\newcommand\medlsquare[4]
{    
    \addplot[thick] coordinates { (#1, #2) (#1+#3, #2) (#1+#3, #2+#3) (#1, #2+#3) (#1, #2)
};
```

I want to reuse the co-ordinates like below

```
\newcommand\medlsquare[4]
{    

    \coordinate (#4A) at (#1, #2);
    \coordinate (#4B) at (#1++3, #2);
    \coordinate (#4C) at (#1+#3, #2+#3);
    \coordinate (#4D) at (#1, #2+#3);
     
    // what is the option do do something like below?
     \addplot[thick] coordinates {/#4A, /#4B, /#4C, /#4D};
};
```

Comment: [tikz pgf - pgfplot addplot with predefined coordinates - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415875/pgfplot-addplot-with-predefined-coordinates) answers are ugly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\addplot` you can use `\draw plot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newcommand{\medlsquare}[4]{%    
    \coordinate (#4A) at (#1, #2);
    \coordinate (#4B) at (#1+#3, #2);
    \coordinate (#4C) at (#1+#3, #2+#3);
    \coordinate (#4D) at (#1, #2+#3);
    \draw plot[thick] coordinates {(#4A) (#4B) (#4C) (#4D) (#4A)};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=0,ymax=3]
        \medlsquare{1}{1}{1}{square}
    \end{axis}

    \draw[red] (squareA) -- (squareC); % created coordinates are still accessible
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]