# Marking a point on parabola (like ellipse)

Tags: tikz-pgf

We can mark a point on ellipse using

> \node[Maroon,draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={-90:$X$}] (X) **at
>   (-120:2cm and 1cm)** {};

**Is there any way to define a point on parabola?**

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\color{Maroon} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin,gray!50](-3,-2) grid (3,2);
\draw[Maroon,thick] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\node[Maroon,draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={-90:$X$}] (X) at (-120:2cm and 1cm) {};

\draw[red] (-1,0) parabola[parabola height=1.5cm] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [your own question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56347/15036)

Comment: @Thruston Using "decoration", i can not define different points on the curve. Here in ellipse, i can define point "X" based on the angle.

Comment: Why can't you just load `decorations.markings` and do `\draw[red,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.2 with {%
\node[red,draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={-90:$Y$}](Y){};}}}] (-1,0) parabola[parabola height=1.5cm] (2,0);`? Here the position plays the same role as the angle, it parametrizes the position of the location.

Comment: @JouleV Yes....

Answer (score 1):

Based on [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) comment...

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\color{Maroon} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin,gray!50](-3,-2) grid (3,2);
\draw[Maroon,thick] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\node[Maroon,draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={-90:$X$}] (X) at (-150:2cm and 1cm) {};

%\draw[red] (-1,0) parabola[parabola height=1.5cm] (2,0);
\draw[red,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with { \node[red,draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={-90:$Y$}](Y){};}}}] (-1,0) parabola[parabola height=1.5cm] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```