# Using tikz: two boxes, two parallel linking edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, parallel

I'd like to have two boxes with text inside them atop one another with some vertical space, and with two parallel vertical edges linking them. With just one such linking edge, tikz makes it easy: `\draw (node1) -- (node2);` (where node1 and node2 specify the two boxes with text).  There's got to be a bit of separation between them; however, I've tried using things like `(node1) +(5pt,0) -- (node2) +(5pt,0)` and frankly it isn't working.  I've tried scoping with shift={(5pt,0),transform shape} and the shift was ignored.  So, how should I do this?  (FYI: there's addtional options on the edges specifying labels and arrows, but I don't believe that they're relevant to this).

Example of single link:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \node at (0,0) (node1) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box1};
    \node at (0,1) (node2) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box2};
    \draw (node1) -- (node2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An ascii version...

```
.  +----+
.  |box1|
.  +----+
.   |  |
. 1 v  ^ 3
.   |  |
.  +----+
.  |box2|
.  +----+
```

(pls ignore the "."s, I needed them to get the code entry to work)

Thank you for your solutions!  I'll definitely be trying them out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you may want to use the `double` and `double distance` keys.

As described in subsubsection 15.3.5 of the `tikz` documentation, using the `double` key in a `\draw` command produces a double line. You can also fine-tune the distance between the two lines with the `double distance` key; using the latter automatically enables `double`, as pointed out in [Claudio's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153710/using-tikz-two-boxes-two-parallel-linking-edges/153714#comment351154_153714). See below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \node at (0,0) (node1) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box1};
    \node at (0,1) (node2) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box2};
    \draw[double distance=5pt] (node1) -- (node2);
    \node at (0,2) (node3) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box1};
    \node at (0,3) (node4) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box2};
    \draw[double distance=10pt] (node3) -- (node4);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: if you need different decorations, labels etc. for the two lines, you need to construct two distinct paths; see below. To draw an arrowhead at the middle of an path, I refer you to [Alain Matthes's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/21891) to [Tikz: Arrowheads in the center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39278/tikz-arrowheads-in-the-center).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    ->-/.style={decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}},
    -<-/.style={decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}},
}

\begin{document}

\def\mydbldist{5pt}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \node at (0,0) (node1) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box1};
    \node at (0,1) (node2) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box2};
    \draw[->-] ([xshift=-.5*\mydbldist]node1.south) -- ([xshift=-.5*\mydbldist]node2.north)
        node[pos=.5,anchor=east] {$1$};
    \draw[-<-] ([xshift=.5*\mydbldist]node1.south) -- ([xshift=.5*\mydbldist]node2.north)
        node[pos=.5,anchor=west] {$3$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are decorations needed on each of the edges, so simply doubling the lines isn't quite there.  I'm going to try to include an ascii version...

Comment: +----+
     |box1|
     +----+
      |  |
    1 v  ^ 3
      |  |
     +----+
     |box2|
     +----+

Comment: For double paths, you don't need `double` option if you specify `double distance`: the latter automatically enables the `double` mode on the path.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I didn't know that, but it makes sense `:)` I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just to show another option. You can use `calc` library and calculate the points on the edges by something like

```
($(node1.south west)!0.33!(node1.south east)$)
```

which is 0.33 (of the total bottom edge length) from the south west of `node1`. This way your points are more accurate.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}

\tikzset{
    ->-/.style={decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}},
    -<-/.style={decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}},
}

\begin{document}

\def\mydbldist{5pt}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \node at (0,0) (node1) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box1};
    \node at (0,1) (node2) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box2};
    \draw[->-] ($(node1.south west)!0.33!(node1.south east)$) -- ($(node2.north west)!.33!(node2.north east)$)
        node[pos=.5,anchor=east] {$1$};
    \draw[-<-] ($(node1.south west)!0.66!(node1.south east)$) -- ($(node2.north west)!.66!(node2.north east)$)
        node[pos=.5,anchor=west] {$3$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My (not so minimal) example is a bit more hackish: you draw manually the two lines exploiting the nodes automatically created when you draw a node shaped as a rectangle (refer to page 420 of the [PGF manual](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)). You shift your position from those "auxiliary" nodes with `[xhift=...,yshift=...]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum height=1cm,text width=5cm,align=center}]
\node (b1) [block] {box1};
\node (b2) [block,below=of b1] {box2};
  \begin{scope}
    \draw [->] ([xshift=-.5cm]b1.south) -- ([xshift=-.5cm]b2.north);
    \draw [->] ([xshift=.5cm]b1.south) -- ([xshift=.5cm]b2.north);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:boxes}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This solution lets you add arrow heads to your lines.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Next code shows an alternative syntax to the one provided by Pier Paolo: `(node.angle)`

> This coordinate refers to a point of the node’s border where a ray
>   shot from the center in the given angle hits the border

With this syntax it's easy to draw parallel lines between node borders.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    block/.style={rectangle,fill=green,minimum height=1cm,text width=2cm,align=center}]
\node[block] (node1) {box1};
\node[block, above=1cm of node1] (node2) {box2};
    \draw [->] (node1.70) -- (node2.-70) node [pos=0.5,right] {1};
    \draw [<-] (node1.110) -- (node2.-110) node [pos=0.5,left] {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks. No need to specify the absolute coordinates!

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\nointerlineskip
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1cm,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]
    \psframebox*{Box 1}\\
    \psframebox*{Box 2}
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{offset=6pt,ArrowInside=->}
\ncline{1,1}{2,1}\naput{3}
\ncline{2,1}{1,1}\naput{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]