# How to make the following picture in the same vertical distance between $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$

Tags: tikz-pic

It seems that the vertical distance between `$\alpha_1,\alpha_2$` is larger than `$\alpha_2,\alpha_3$`. I post my code in the following

```
\tikzset{%
    mypoint/.style={circle, fill=black},
    middlearrow/.style={% this code is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39283/101651
        decoration={markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[scale=2]{#1}} ,
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=2.5em, row sep=8ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt] {%
        %first row
        \node (startrow1) {}; &&&
        \node[mypoint, label={[above,yshift=2pt]$\binom{\alpha_3}{0}$}] (B1) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[above,yshift=2pt]$\binom{\alpha_3}{1}$}] (B2) {}; &&
        %\node[mypoint, label={[above,yshift=2pt]$\beta_{3}$}] (B3) {}; &&
        \node[text width=3em, align=center] (endrow1) {$\alpha_3$};
        \\
        %second row
        \node (startrow2) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt] $\binom{\alpha_2}{0}$}] (A1) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt] $\binom{\alpha_2}{1}$}] (A2) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt] $\binom{\alpha_2}{2}$}] (A3) {}; &&
        \node[text width=2.5em, align=center] (endrow2) {$\alpha_2$};
        \\
         %third row
        \node (startrow3) {}; &
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt]$\binom{\alpha_1}{0}$}] (C1) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt]$\binom{\alpha_1}{1}$}] (C2) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt]$\binom{\alpha_1}{2}$}] (C3) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt]$\binom{\alpha_1}{3}$}] (C4) {}; &&
        \node[text width=2.0em, align=center] (endrow3) {$\alpha_1$};
        \\
        };
    \draw[dashed] (startrow1) -- (B1)
    (B2) -- (endrow1)
    (startrow2) -- (A1)
    (A3) -- (endrow2)
    (startrow3) -- (C1)
    (C3) -- (endrow3);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (B1) -- (B2);
   % \draw[middlearrow={<}] (B2) -- (B3);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (A1) -- (A2);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (A2) -- (A3);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}, dashed] (A1) -- (B1);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}] (B1) -- (A2);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}] (A2) -- (B2);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}] (B2) -- (A3);
  %  \draw[middlearrow={>}, dashed] (A3) -- (B3);
     \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C1) -- (C2);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C2) -- (C3);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C3) -- (C4);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}, dashed] (C1) -- (A1);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C2) -- (A1);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C2) -- (A2);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (A2) -- (C3);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C3) -- (A3);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}, dashed] (A3) -- (C4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distance between columns and rows is fixed after nodes are completed. Then as second row nodes include labels below, third row dots are placed `8ex` below the label and not below the second row dots.

You can first draw the dots matrix and later on add the binomial labels or can include a `phantom` label on first row to force similar distance between rows, like in following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    mypoint/.style={circle, fill=black},
    middlearrow/.style={% this code is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39283/101651
        decoration={markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[scale=2]{#1}} ,
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
]
    \matrix[column sep=2.5em, row sep=8ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt] {%
        %first row
        \node (startrow1) {}; &&&
        \node[mypoint, label={[above,yshift=2pt]$\binom{\alpha_3}{0}$},
                            label={[below,yshift=-22pt] \phantom{$\binom{\alpha_2}{0}$}}] (B1) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[above,yshift=2pt]$\binom{\alpha_3}{1}$}] (B2) {}; &&
        %\node[mypoint, label={[above,yshift=2pt]$\beta_{3}$}] (B3) {}; &&
        \node[text width=3em, align=center] (endrow1) {$\alpha_3$};
        \\
        %second row
        \node (startrow2) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt] $\binom{\alpha_2}{0}$}] (A1) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt] $\binom{\alpha_2}{1}$}] (A2) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt] $\binom{\alpha_2}{2}$}] (A3) {}; &&
        \node[text width=2.5em, align=center] (endrow2) {$\alpha_2$};
        \\
         %third row
        \node (startrow3) {}; &
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt]$\binom{\alpha_1}{0}$}] (C1) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt]$\binom{\alpha_1}{1}$}] (C2) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt]$\binom{\alpha_1}{2}$}] (C3) {}; &&
        \node[mypoint, label={[below,yshift=-22pt]$\binom{\alpha_1}{3}$}] (C4) {}; &&
        \node[text width=2.0em, align=center] (endrow3) {$\alpha_1$};
        \\
        };
    \draw[dashed] (startrow1) -- (B1)
    (B2) -- (endrow1)
    (startrow2) -- (A1)
    (A3) -- (endrow2)
    (startrow3) -- (C1)
    (C3) -- (endrow3);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (B1) -- (B2);
   % \draw[middlearrow={<}] (B2) -- (B3);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (A1) -- (A2);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (A2) -- (A3);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}, dashed] (A1) -- (B1);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}] (B1) -- (A2);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}] (A2) -- (B2);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}] (B2) -- (A3);
  %  \draw[middlearrow={>}, dashed] (A3) -- (B3);
     \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C1) -- (C2);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C2) -- (C3);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C3) -- (C4);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}, dashed] (C1) -- (A1);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C2) -- (A1);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C2) -- (A2);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (A2) -- (C3);
    \draw[middlearrow={<}] (C3) -- (A3);
    \draw[middlearrow={>}, dashed] (A3) -- (C4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is related to the labels of the points. You could use `yshift=-27pt` for all the labels of the points in the first row (maybe play around a bit that value of `yshift`). By this, the labels of the first row will appear below the points, and the space between α₁,α₂ and α₂,α₃ will be equal.