# drawing figures using tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, floats, draw

I'm struggling at drawing some figures using tikz package, i've succeeded drawing the three main linse that meet at the point A, however i'm struggling drawing the two small arrows, can someone help me please ?

Here is what i wanna draw :

[image]

Here is what i succeeded drawing : [image]

Don't worry about the x and the o i know how to draw them, it's the small arrows that are giving me hard time here is my code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (4,0) -- (4,2);
        \draw (4,0) -- (6,-2);              
        \draw (4,0) -- (2,-2);                                              
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Alain Matthes answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/59521), you can do it like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (4,0) -- (4,2);
        \draw[->-=.5] (4,0) -- (6,-2);              
        \draw[->-=.5] (2,-2) -- (4,0);                                              
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough you know that right ?! i've been trying to reach for a solution for two days thank you thank you and thank you again sir !

Answer (score 1):

Or without using the decoration

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (4,0);
        \draw (A) -- (4,2);
        \draw (2,-2) -- (A) node [sloped, pos=.5] {>} -- (6,-2) node [sloped, pos=.5] {>};                                             
        \fill (A) circle [radius=2pt];
        \node [right=3pt of A] {$A$};
        \node [below=3ex of A] {\large$X$};
        \node [above left=3ex of A] {\large$O$};
        \node [above right=3ex of A] {\large$O$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you accept my answer because I also placed the nodes? IMHO Christoph90's one is far more elegant (see upvotes)!

Comment: I wanted to accept both codes but i realized it wasn't possible because both your codes work and make exactly what i wanted thank you both Nbur and Christoph90's

Answer (score 0):

Also, very straightforward with `pstricks-add` package. Compile with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
  \psset{arrowsize=4pt 3}
  \psline {*-}(4,0)(4,2)
  \psline [ArrowInside=->,ArrowInsidePos=0.5](2,-2)(4,0)(6,-2) 
  \uput{07pt}[0](4,0){$A$} 
  \uput{20pt}[45](4,0){$O$} 
  \uput{20pt}[135](4,0){$O$} 
  \uput{20pt}[-90](4,0){$X$} 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]