# Symmetrization and antisymmetrization of tensor products

Tags: math-mode, tensor

How do I achieve something like

[image]

or

[image]

in LaTeX? The curved lines indicate symmetrization with respect to the indices they join, and the straight lines indicate antisymmetrization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpleminded proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
$u^{\tikzmarknode{i1}{i}\tikzmarknode{j1}{j}}
\tikzmarknode{v1}{v}^{\tikzmarknode{k1}{k}\tikzmarknode{l1}{\ell}}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[blue,thick] (i1.north east) to[out=30,in=150] (l1.north west);
\draw[blue,thick] (j1) -- ++(0,-1.5ex)  -| (k1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
$u^{\tikzmarknode{i1}{i}\tikzmarknode{j1}{j}}
\tikzmarknode{v1}{v}^{\tikzmarknode{k1}{k}\tikzmarknode{l1}{\ell}}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[blue,thick] (i1.north east) to[out=30,in=150] (l1.north west);
\draw[blue,thick] (j1) -- ([yshift=-2pt]v1.south -| j1)  -| (k1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
$u^{\tikzmarknode{i2}{i}\tikzmarknode{j2}{j}}
\tikzmarknode{v2}{v}^{\tikzmarknode{k2}{k}\tikzmarknode{l2}{\ell}}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[blue,thick] (j2.north east) to[out=30,in=150] (k2.north west);
\draw[blue,thick] (i2) -- ([yshift=-2pt]v2.south -| i2)  -| (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
$u^{\tikzmarknode{i3}{i}\tikzmarknode{j3}{j}}
\tikzmarknode{v3}{v}^{\tikzmarknode{k3}{k}\tikzmarknode{l3}{\ell}}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[blue,thick,rounded corners=2pt] (j3) --
([yshift=-2pt]v3.south -| j3) -| (k3);
\draw[blue,thick] (i3.north) -- ++(0,3pt)  -| (l3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In your code, I suppose v1 isn’t being used.

Comment: Can you perhaps edit your answer to include the symmetrization below and antisymmetrization above as well? I couldn't get them to work in spite of using something like "\draw[red,thick] (j1.south west) to [out=300,in=225] (k1.south west);"

Comment: @leastaction Sorry, was hibernating. Added some more options.

Comment: Thanks. I meant to ask if it is possible to swap the curve with the |__| (i.e. the curve below, and the |---| above).

Comment: @leastaction I added a proposal. If you want things to be like in the last example, one may actually use Wick contractions for that, i.e. one may [modify the package commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451945/121799) to give you that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Also with pstricks (compile with xelatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

$u^{\rnode{i}{i}\rnode{j}{j}} v^{\rnode{k}{k}\rnode{l}{\ell}}$ 
\ncarc[linecolor=blue,nodesep=1pt,arcangle=60]{i}{l}
\ncbar[linecolor=blue,nodesep=1pt,arm=3pt,angle=-90]{j}{k}

\end{document}
```

> [image]