# A wheel-like figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles, shading

I am trying to draw a wheel-like figure like this. I had used xfig.

[image]

I wonder whether I can also use LaTex tikz or other ways to get similar figure with the additional criterion

> - the area enclosed by the four red rectangulars/squares --- should have been filled in with **a gray shaded but still transparent color** (like tunable transparency 10%, 30%, 50%, 70% for each wing of the 4 wings of the wheel) or so.

Do any experts know how to do this?

Thank you! (I will accept the answer very soon)

Comment: XFig supports LaTeX export.  ([Screenshot of the export menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l37Y5.png))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question. -1 for the same reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, LaTeX can do such things.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=5,>=stealth]
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{60}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \draw[thick,blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.7);
 \foreach \X/\Y in {0/0.2,90/0.3,180/0.4,270/0.5}
 {\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\X}{0}{0}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
  \draw[thick,->-=0.075,->-=0.575,fill=gray,opacity=\Y] (0.1,0,0) -- (1.6,0,0) -- (1.6,0,1.5) -- (0.1,0,1.5) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick,red,->-=0.4,->-=0.9] (0.2,0,0.1) -- (0.2,0,1.4)  -- (1.5,0,1.4) --
  (1.5,0,0.1) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}}
 \draw[->,blue,thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=20:-200,samples=31,smooth] ({0.3*sin(\x)},{0.3*cos(\x)},1.8);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks +1 - you are the tikz god! Can you remind me the function to tune the transparency of the shade area?

Comment: @annieheart `opacity=<value>`. In this example the four planes have the opacitie `0.2` ... `0.5`, i.e. the `\Y` value in the foreach loop.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `->-` is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/121799.