# How to draw arrows on each arc and line in \path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

When I draw paths:

```
 \path [draw=blue] 
 (0,0) 
 arc(-60:60:1.732) 
 arc(120:240:1.732);
```

I want to add an arrow in the middle of each arc within this \path.

Like this:

[image]

I have tried the "show path construction" (curveto code) style in the package decorations.pathreplacing. However It doesn't create decoration on each arc, but every 90 degrees (or less than 90 degrees). This is because the "curveto code" in "show path construction" create decorations for each Bezier curve, and one circle is created by 4 Bezier curves.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I want to tell you that *using only one `\path` throughout the picture is **not** recommended*, and you should *really* use as many `\path`s as possible if there are different types of lines drawn.

If you want to compress many lines to a single `\path`, you need something like the `edge` operation. Unfortunately, `edge` doesn't accept `arc` or similar as its option, so I use `out` and `in` here. Therefore, the output curves are not exactly the curves in some circles. I hope it is close enough.

I also made some developments to `middlearrow` style in [ferahfeza's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484627/156344), so that it can handle the nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    middlearrow/.style n args={3}{
        draw,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with {
                \arrow{#1};
                \path[#2] node {$#3$};
            },
        },
        postaction=decorate
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\coordinate (x) at (0,0);
\coordinate (y) at (0,3);
\path (x)   edge[out=60,in=-60,middlearrow={<}{left}{b}] (y)
            edge[out=30,in=-30,middlearrow={>}{right}{s}] (y)
            edge[out=120,in=-120,middlearrow={<}{right}{a}] (y)
            edge[out=150,in=-150,middlearrow={>}{left}{r}] (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much JouleV! Yes, `edge` works very well. Sometimes I use edge to draw some illustrative diagrams when accurate controlling is not necessary. In some cases, I need accurate length and angles of arcs (with middle arrows on them).

Comment: Previously I mainly used the second solution under this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line, but it will add more than one arrow when the angles of arcs are greater than 90. The reason is that, as I said in the description of the question, the number of arrows is determined by the number of Bezier curves. If the angle of an `arc` greater than 90, at least two Bezier curves is used to create the arc.

Comment: @Frank Of course you can choose anything you want. This is only my proposal.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I really apreciate your effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Define `\path` for each arc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
% Middlearrow code is from:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39283
\tikzset{middlearrow/.style={
        decoration={markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{#1}} ,
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.5mm,>=stealth]
 \path [draw=blue,middlearrow={>}] 
 (0,0) 
 arc(-60:60:1.732)coordinate (A) node[midway,right,yshift=-1mm]{$s$} ;

\path [draw=blue,middlearrow={<}] 
 (0,0) 
 arc(-30:30:3)node[midway,left,yshift=-0.75mm]{$b$};

 \path [draw=blue,middlearrow={>}] 
 (0,0) 
 arc(240:120:1.732)node[midway,left,yshift=-1mm]{$r$} ;

 \path [draw=blue,middlearrow={<}] 
 (0,0) 
 arc(210:150:3)node[midway,right,yshift=-1mm]{$a$} ;

\fill [blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);
\fill [blue] (A) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any other solution which needs only one \path? I want to use relative coordinates to draw arcs.

Comment: @Frank What do you mean by "relative coordinates"? Is two `path`s solution ok, because there are two types of arrow? Moreover, why do you want only one path? Four paths cost you nothing at all.

Comment: @JouleV I mean I may use say two or more `arc`s in one `path`, with each `arc` connected end to end, and each decorated by an arrow. The two path solution is OK. Thank you for your reply.