# Tikz oriented simplex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a triangle with orientation but I am not able to get it done. Please help me out.
I also want to insert a circular arrow in the center.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots,bm,tikz-cd}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.geometric,decorations.markings, calc, fadings, decorations.pathreplacing, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 90] (0,0) -- +(.2a5,0);}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [black,line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- (1.5,2.6) -- (3,0) -- cycle;
    \draw [thick] (0,0) -- node {\midarrow} (3,0);
    \draw [thick] (1.5,2.6) -- node {\midarrow} (3,0);
    \draw [thick] (1.5,2.6) -- node {\midarrow} (0,0);
    \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (3 pt);
    \filldraw[black] (3,0) circle (3 pt);
    \filldraw[black] (1.5,2.6) circle (3 pt);
    \node [below left] at (0,0) {\textbf{a}};
    \node [above] at (1.5,2.6) {\textbf{b}};
    \node [below right] at (3,0) {\textbf{c}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this? The arrows in the middle are taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/121799) and the `/.list` key allows one to draw several of those, and using nodes and labels allows us to pack everything into one path. I also removed packages and libraries that are not needed for this triangle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta,bending}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={markings, % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/121799
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[line width=2pt]{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner
sep=3pt,label={[font=\bfseries]#1}},>=latex]
    \draw [black,line width=1.5pt,->-/.list={1/6,1/2,5/6}] 
    (210:3) node[bullet={below left:a}] (a) {}
    -- (90:3) node[bullet={above:b}] (b) {}
    -- (-30:3) node[bullet={below right:c}] (c) {}
    -- cycle;
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,-{Latex[bend]}] (240:0.5) arc(240:-60:0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can the arrows be bigger? And what about the circular arrow?

Comment: @user473334 Sure. I updated the answer. If you want a full circle arrow use e.g. `\draw[line width=1.5pt,-{Latex[bend]}] (270:0.5) arc(270:-120:0.5);`

Comment: +1 Cute use of list:)