# How to evaluate an angle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possibile to evaluate an angle in Tikz? I googled a lot but I can't find anything exhausting.
My problem is the following: I have an arc intersected by a bundle of parallel lines, like shawn in the picture below

[image]

Once drawn the arc (path name=mirror) I used this code

```
\foreach \y in {-1.6,-0.8,...,1.6}
                {
                    \path [name path=ray] (-1,\y) -- ($ (-1,\y) + (10,0) $);
                    \path [name intersections={of=ray and mirror, by={P}}];
                    \draw [thick, postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}] (-1,\y) -- (P);
                    \draw [thick, dashed, name path=refracted] (P) -- (F);

                    \begin{scope}[shift={(P)}]

                    \end{scope}                     
                }
```

to generate the bundle of lines. I would like to draw some lines like these in red

[image]

To do this, I thought to evaluate the angle between P--F--V and, after a shift of the coordinate system in P (which changes for each line), then draw a simply line using

```
\draw [thick] (\myAngle:2cm);
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`? BTW, the computation of the angle is already done in the lowest example of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520724/194703.

Comment: I'm writing something like a book, it would be impossible I guess

Comment: Have a look at the `calc` library (you seem to already use it).  There is a way to do exactly what you ask for.

Comment: You also expect the answer to be self-contained, don't you? It is for all of us some effort to provide some minimal compilable codes, but this is the only reasonable way of communicating here, I think.

Comment: Oh I got you... Excuse me for my last posts then, you are definetely right. I'll post the entire code on next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The computation you are asking for is simpler than the one in [the previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520724/194703) since the rays are all horizontal. You just need to get the angle, alpha, at which they hit the mirror, and outgoing ray will have an angle of 180-2*alpha. This angle can be computed with the `calc` syntax

```
\path let \p1=($(<point>)-(<center>)$),
    \n1={180-atan2(\y1,\x1)} in ... ;
```

where `<point>` is the point at which the ray hits the mirror, i.e. the intersection point `P` in your code, and `<center>` is the center of the circle used to draw the mirror. The following self-contained code illustrates this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc,angles,quotes}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{halo}{\pgfpointorigin}{
  color(0pt)=(pgftransparent!100); color(22.5bp)=(pgftransparent!100);
  color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!00); color(50bp)=(pgftransparent!00)}%
\pgfdeclarefading{halo}{\pgfuseshading{halo}}%
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/194703
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}},
  ->-/.default=0.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every label/.append style={black},
    bullet/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=0.1em}]
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \clip (75:-3)
    -- (75:-2.5) arc (75:-75:-2.5)
    -- (-75:-3) arc (-75:75:-3);
    \fill[path fading=halo] (0,0) circle[radius=3cm];
\end{scope}
\draw (-2,0) coordinate (L) -- (7,0) coordinate (R) 
  (3,0)  node[bullet,label=below left:$V$](V){}
  (6,0)  node[bullet,label=below:$C$](C){}
  (-1,0)  node[bullet,label=below:$O$](O){}
  foreach \X [count=\Y] in {-40,-20,20,40}
  {($(C)+(180+\X:3)$) node[bullet](P\Y){}};
  \foreach \Y in {1,...,4}
  {\draw[orange,->-,thick] (O|-P\Y) -- (P\Y);
   \draw[red,->-,thick] let \p1=($(P\Y)-(C)$),
    \n1={180-atan2(\y1,\x1)} in
    (P\Y) -- ++({180-2*\n1}:2);
   \draw[dashed, shorten >=-2cm] (C) -- (P\Y);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]