# Plotting a 3D vector

Tags: tikz-3dplot, vector, tikz-3d, pst-3dplot

I want to plot this 3D vector using tikz3D .Since I'm new to Latex, I find this task a bit difficult. I saw a couple of similar sort of questions in this forum but their pictorial representations are a bit different to this. It would be appreciated if anybody could help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Equation of the line?

Comment: @manooooh I edited the question to indicate the vector equation.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I changed the original image by mistake. Corrected it now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/194703
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}},
  ->-/.default=0.5}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{125}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line cap=round,>=stealth]
 \draw (-3,0,0) --  (3,0,0)  node[pos=1.05]{$x$};
 \draw (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0) node[pos=1.05]{$y$};
 \draw (0,0,-3) -- (0,0,3) node[pos=1.05]{$z$};
 \draw (2,0,0) node[below]{$2$} -- ++ (0,0,0.15)
 (0,2,0) node[below]{$2$} -- ++ (0,0,0.15)
 (0,0,-2) node[right]{$-2$} -- ++ (0,-0.15,0)
 (0,0,2) node[right]{$2$} -- ++ (0,-0.15,0);
 \draw[very thick,->-=0.7] (-1.5,3.5,-3)  -- (1.5,0.5,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I changed the vector. Anyways, I could get an idea of how to plot it by looking at your answer

Comment: How can we indicate the Y-intercept and Z-intercept?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy What do you mean by that?

Comment: I meant how can I indicate 2 on Y & Z axes.

Comment: @SL_MathGuy I added them.