# arrows on picture in overleaf

Tags: arrows

I have a problem, don't know how to put this two arrows on picture. You can see picture how need to be and where I stuck with that. Also I provide code that you can see what I done till now.Thanks for helping

[image: image what I need]

[image: image what I have]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!3]
\tikzstyle{edge}={->,thick}

\node[vertex] (v1) at (1,2) {1};
\node[vertex] (v2) at (2,0) {2};
\node[vertex] (v3) at (0,-2) at {3};

 \draw[directed] (v1) -- (v3);
\draw[directed] (v2) -- (v1);
 \draw[directed] (v3) -- (v2);



\path (v3) edge [bend left] node[] {}(v1);
\path (v2) edge [bend right] node[] {}(v1);
\draw (1,-0.3) node[bellow]{2};
\draw (0.4,1) node[right]{1};
\draw (1.3,0.8) node[above]{1};
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: thanks to notice that, this is my first question, I will fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,quotes}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/194703
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}},
  ->-/.default=0.55}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[vertex/.style={circle,fill=black!3},>=stealth,auto,
    directed/.style={->-,thick}]
 \path foreach \X in {1,2,3} 
 { (210-120*\X:2) node[vertex](v\X){$\mathsf{\X}$} };
 \path[every edge/.append style={directed},bend angle=15] 
 (v3) edge[bend left,"$1$"] (v1)  edge["$1$"'] (v2)
 (v2) edge[bend right,"$1$"'] (v1)
 (v1) edge[bend left,"$1$"] (v3)
 (v1) edge[bend right,"$1$"'] (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]