# Directed circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, circles

How I can draw a directed circle?

For example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is a circle, but it is not a directed circle.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is a directed circle? Could you add a figure as an example?

Comment: @carLaTeX Thank you. I need to draw a circle with direction same as loop in graphs.

Comment: I guess you mean you want an arrow on the circle, so see if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7458/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108959/ help.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you